# How do I change the color of each character of a word on the same line in HTML5?

Tags: html, textcolor, text-coloring

I have been working on something where I am making a rainbow of blocks using an [app that teaches you HTML5](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tursky.jan.nauc.sa.html5). I have a diagram where the blocks are arranged in the shape of a rainbow and are colored to look like a rainbow.

I am trying to do this: RAINBOW where R is red, A is orange, I is yellow, N is green, B is blue, O is indigo, and W is violet (the colors of the rainbow). And my only problem is making the characters in the same line different colors.

I've tried this:

```html
<p style="color:red;">R</p>
<p style="color:orange;">A</p>
<p style="color:yellow;">I</p>
<p style="color:green;">N</p>
<p style="color:blue;">B</p>
<p style="color:indigo;">O</p>
<p style="color:violet;">W</p>
```

but when I do it for each letter, of course it makes 7 different paragraphs and i want it on the same line. How can I fix this problem?

Comment: I've tried <p style="color:red;">R</p>

Comment: Link to app: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=tursky.jan.nauc.sa.html5

Answer (score 1):

The problem is that you are using a `p` element for each letter. `p` is a block element, and block elements occupy the whole width available and start in a new line (causing the problem).

The solution: use an inline element instead (for example, `span`). Then all the letters will be displayed inline instead of each on a new line:

```html
<span style="color:red;">R</span >
<span style="color:orange;">A</span >
<span style="color:yellow;">I</span >
<span style="color:green;">N</span >
<span style="color:blue;">B</span >
<span style="color:indigo;">O</span >
<span style="color:violet;">W</span >
```